# How can I resolve 400 bad request in Google Picker dialog in test application?

Tags: google-api-client, google-picker

I'm running into trouble with test users and the `Picker` component in my web applicaton.

A subset of my test users are receiving a `400: The server cannot process the request because it is malformed when attempting to access the picker.` Some of them experience a looping sign-in beforehand.

The picker is constructed in the following way inside of a `useEffect` in a React component:

```js
// if there's a non-config related bug, I would imagine it must be related to getting the access token here.
const accessToken = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;

const view = new picker.DocsView(picker.ViewId.DOCUMENTS);
view.setIncludeFolders(true);

const pickerDisplay = new picker.PickerBuilder()
                            .enableFeature(picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
                            .setAppId(appId)
                            .addView(view)
                            .addView(new picker.DocsUploadView())
                            .setOAuthToken(accessToken)
                            .setDeveloperKey(apiKey)
                            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
                            .build();
setPicker(pickerDisplay); // sets picker state
```

Because I am not receiving the error message and the application has not been verified, I believe this likely has something to do with the IAM.

- I believe I've been able to eliminate managed browsers settings,
  cookie settings, and extensions as possible sources of error.
- I've also added the users to the GCP project with the Browser role, though
  they did not receive invites. What do I need to try next to resolve
  this issue?

I cannot provide a minimum reproducible example because this only seems to be confined to a subset of my users' browsers.

I reached out to Google support, but unfortunately this is not covered.

I need to get this application into production relatively soon, so I'm very seriously considering just writing my own Drive microservice and recreating the Picker. I would love to avoid this though.

Comment: Did you allow 3rd party cookies on the browser? As per your `const accessToken = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getAuthResponse().access_token;` you want to get an OAuth token from the sign in credentials on the browser? What happens if you call the [OAuth dialog](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs) box like `gapi.load('auth2', onAuthApiLoad);`

Comment: Right now, I'm calling `gapi.load('client:auth2', onLoad)` in a context provider. On every machine that I can test or spoof, that works just fine.  But, I'll push a build with just `'auth2'` instead. Should there be a difference?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, sorry for the delay, do you have a sandbox with your code? remove any key, I just want to see the logic you're using

Comment: Hi @Imonninger, did you manage to solve this? We're in the same boat!

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not. There was never a clear reason for the behavior amongst those users. The only common factor that we identified was that they had their devices were provisioned by their tech ops team after a certain date. We suspected this meant some details of the provisioning, likely either browser config or GSuite auth, had affected their ability to use the feature. However, we were never able to do more than hypothesize before the project folded.